# Share whiteboard with other user using node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io-1.0

I need some idea regarding whiteboard sharing with other users.Suppose one admin user wants to share his whiteboard with one user.What he is writing/erasing on/from whiteboard this will display to other user.The other user can only read from the white board.I want to implement this using Node.js and socket.io.Can anybody give me some idea or reference link for how to implement this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a room system for your app, http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ , check docs and try to integrate with a basic chat application firstly. If you want to draw a whiteboard, that's the another area which is unrelated with socket.io , you can use canvas libraries([fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) seems a handy library with a lot of demos(for your requirement [free-drawing demo](http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/))) for creating whiteboard and then you can integrate whiteboard events in socket.io cleint-side with ease.

Comment: @ llker : I know how to socket.io will implement but i need to make a white board.For that i need a good resource.

Comment: @satya I gave a demo link in answer fabric.js , you can take a look.

Comment: @ llker : i am checking this.Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome, if answer is helpful for you, please give your feedback.

Comment: @ llker : i am doing that once succeed i must inform you.